why this error "No space left on device while appending to file" can happen in insert and update in ArangoDB?
Hi I have encountered this exception while I want to insert or update in ArangoDB. I just wonder why this error occurred because the document which I want to insert or update is not too huge and our ArangoDB maintainer said we had 160 GB free space. our application is based on java with spring if could be helpful in finding the solution and our Arango version is 3.8.6. here is the exception with detailed trace and our dependencies in pom.xml. I will appreciate for any fruitful answer or comment.
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arangodb-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>6.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-velocypack</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.arangodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocypack</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

the trace of the exception:
 com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 500, Error: 1104 - 10 error: No space left on deviceWhile appending to file: /data/arangodb/data/dbserver8530/data/engine-rocksdb/679192.sst: No space left on device at com.arangodb.internal.util.ResponseUtils.checkError (ResponseUtils.java:55)

PLEASE read and consider Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Hint: fixing your question will increase the chance that someone will answer it ...

In addition, you need to provide a lot more information.  For example, the output from running df -k on the machine you are running that code on.  (Assuming it is a Linux box.)  The "No space left on device" error comes from the operating system, and (AFAIK) it only happens when the file system has filled up.

Thank you for your feedback I edited my question
